# Add a seperator after a fixed number of widgets in a grid

Tags: flutter, dart

I am displaying over 5000 images using `GridView.Builder`. I am fetching data from firebase realtime database. Initially I am fetching only 50 records but when the user reaches the bottom of grid list, I fetch another 50 records and so on. The code is working fine.

Now after every 200 images, I want to show a `Container` widget with `height`: 250 and `width`: `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width`. How do I do that?

```
StreamBuilder(
        stream: listStream,
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<WatchFace>> snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          } else {
            return GridView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                gridDelegate: 
                SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 2,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 1,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 1,
                  childAspectRatio: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width /
                      (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.3),
                ),
                controller: _controller,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Padding(
                    padding:
                        const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2, horizontal: 3),
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border:
                            Border.all(color: Colors.pinkAccent, width: 0.8),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                      ),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text('${snapshot.data[index].date}'), // Later I will display network image here.
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                });
          }
        },
      ),
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work :

1. Wrap your item with `Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min)`
2. Put this after the item :

```
if(index != 0 && index % 200 == 0)
  YourContainer(),
```

EDIT : just remembered the `GridView`'s `childAspectRatio` thing. It will force the size of every cell, so you can't add space. You might want to take a look at [slivers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ORiTTaVY6mM)